# Emgu CV and the official Microsoft Kinect SDK?

Tags: emgucv, kinect, openni

[Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) currently allows the [use of the Kinect with the OpenNI drivers](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#Kinect_On_Windows).

I've also seen that there exists an [mssdk-openni bridge](https://www.assembla.com/code/kinect-mssdk-openni-bridge/git/nodes/) application to allow the Kinects running on the official Microsoft SDK to emulate OpenNI driven Kinects.

Has anyone been successful in getting a Kinect running on the Microsoft SDK to work with Emgu CV, either with the mssdk-openni bridge or directly?

Are there any tips on getting it running smoothly, or pitfalls to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. I've simply installed the SDK and could capture and extract bitmaps of the video stream. The MSSDK for Kinect works just fine and easy. You can start by reading the Samples specially the Skeleton Sample and KinectColorViewer, KinectDepthViewer and KinectDiagnosticViewer wpf samples provided by Microsoft. You can add Emgu CV dlls and use them both together to gain your goal. 
Good Luck