# Using static image in EmguCV capture

Tags: emgucv

I am currently using

```
Capture grabber = new Emgu.CV.Capture(@"M2U00253.wmv");
grabber.QueryFrame();
```

I want to know that how can I use an image file(.jpg) instead of the video file(.mpg)?

Comment: Just invoke `Image<>` constructor with desired channel format (e.g. `Bgr`) with file name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To load a static you can use the following method,

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("MyImage.jpg");
```

refer to [this link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your responses.... can i also know how to take data from kinect and later process it using emguCV???

Comment: Hi, you can check the following thread to find out how to process data from kinect
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821575/using-kinect-with-emgu-cv