# Covert Kinect v2 ColorFrame into EmguCV Image<Bgr, byte>

Tags: kinect, emgucv

I want to convert ColorFrame of Kinect V2 SDK into Image i.e. Image format of EmguCV. Converting ColorFrame into BitmapSource then BitmapSource into Bitmap and finally Bitmap into EmguCV Image seems to be unnecessary overhead to CPU.
Below is the code-

```
private byte[] pixels = null;
this.pixels = new byte[colorFrameDescription.Width * colorFrameDescription.Height * colorFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel];

using (ColorFrame colorFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
{
    if (colorFrame != null)
    {
        FrameDescription colorFrameDescription = colorFrame.FrameDescription;
        if (colorFrame.RawColorImageFormat == ColorImageFormat.Bgra)
            colorFrame.CopyRawFrameDataToArray(pixels);
        else
            colorFrame.CopyConvertedFrameDataToArray(this.pixels, ColorImageFormat.Bgra);

        //Initialize Emgu CV image then assign byte array of pixels to it
        Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(colorFrameDescription.Width, colorFrameDescription.Height);
        img.Bytes = pixels;

        imgBox.Image = img;//Show image in Emgu.CV.UI.ImageBox
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821575/using-kinect-with-emgu-cv